# after installing my theme i still getting custom magento theme

Tags: theme

I have installed theme mapple and others whose folder structure are like this

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\default
blank
default
iphone
mapple
```

Comment: Did you clear the cache? and Also make sure you define your theme in `System > Configuration > Design` section from admin.

Comment: can you share your design configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing all the cache and then set your default theme to be Mapple in `system->configuration->design -> package` and theme both.
If still your theme is not visible try by turning template path hints on from

`system->configuration->developer-Template Settings.`

It will show you the path from where the files are loaded!

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the theme, you will need to enable that theme, either from

```
system > configuration > Design or you can be enabled it from System > Design.
```

You still have to configure the theme as per the user guide if they are providing like pages, static blocks etc.

Answer (score 0):

1) `System->Configuration->Design->Themes` and provide the theme name in Default field (which will change your default theme to this new theme) and click “Save Config” button at the top right corner of your screen.

2) Sometimes `Magento Cache` doesn’t let you see your changes instantly. In order to test your new theme it would be wise to disable cache for the time being. Go to System > Cache Management and select “Disable” then click “Save Cache”. Once you are done with all the steps Enable the cache again.